# Y510P Fedora doesn't start X after faulty drivers installation

Tags: fedora, intel, nvidia, sli

I have a Lenovo Y510P with integrated IntelHD 4th gen. VGA and a dedicated Nvidia GT755 VGA.
I run Fedora 21 and until recently had no problems. I never installed any proprietary drivers or special tools to deal with graphics, it just worked under fedora.
(I use a Windows partition to play games, everything there works fine too.)

Quite recently I acquired a second GT755 for my Ultrabay-Slot. Booting to Windows went without a problem, SLI activated like a charm and everything seemed fine. However, booting to fedora caused the CPU to rapidly heat up. I found out later that having both VGAs installed causes the bios to disable IntelHD, which apparently was the only VGA Fedora can run out of the box.
So my first try was to install VGA drivers and IntelHD-drivers in parallel.
(following this guide: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/36506/changing-default-driver-for-displaying-x/ )
After I found out about the "no IntelHD with SLI"-problem I tried out to get the SLI disabled and rely only on my Intel. There I made a huge mistake:
In the bios, I disabled the GT755 while booting with only one VGA. Forgetting about that, I later tried to install the Nvidia driver again, which could not find the implemented GT755. Believing this was due to some xorg.conf-code within /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

I simply plugged in the second GT755, which caused the bios to disable IntelHD.
Now I installed the Nvidia Driver (bumblebee-nvidia) and everything worked fine, xorg.conf was rewritten autmatically, I disabled nouveau in /etc/default/grub and recompild grub (with grub2-mkconfig -o grub.cfg), and rebooted.
Since then, I could not get to the login-screen. When I enter my LUKS-passwd, I see a yellow Message:

```
[    0.093961] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
```

But if I remember correctly, this was always displayed, just in white.

I have tried reverting to my backups of xorg.conf, grub.cfg and /etc/default/grub and recompiling grub, nothing worked.
Everything was tested with both enabled and disabled internal GT755.
I tried to reinstall bumblebee-nvidia with enabled GT755, no difference.
IntelHD drivers are loaded at startup and appear to be correctly configured in all xorg related confs.
Calling startx causes the login-screen to flash for a moment, just to be instantly replased by an error-message:

```
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
waiting for X server to shut down "sni-qt/[NUMBER, 4 digits]" WARN [TIMESTAMP] void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE bluedevil-monolithic: Fatal IO error: client killed(EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

At this point I would be glad to get my display back. Ideally however, I want to be able to keep the second VGA in it's slot and still use IntelHD, since I will never require high VGA performance under fedora.
**What I need now is a possibility to revert my system back to it's old state.**
With any luck I can actually install all required drivers afterwards and would write a little VGA-guide for the Y510P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I broke the displaymanager (sddm) somewhere somehow.
A friend helped me analysing the problem, but we were unable to find the exact cause.
We fixed the problem by replacing sddm with kdm.
the steps are:
install kdm

```
sudo yum install kdm
```

disable sddm:

```
sudo systemct disable sddm
```

reboot